# Unable to get session to work for login site php 7.2

Tags: php, session

I'm learning PHP so i'm creating a login site. When the user enters valid credentials the page should be directed to /site.php however it gets re-directed back to index.php when valid creds are entered. I'm doing this with a domain www.example.xyz on port 8080 running on apache2.

I have tested that sessions are working by testing the following in new files:
https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_sessions.asp

I'm just not sure what i'm doing wrong in my code

I know the connection to the database is good because I've tested the code without any session handling and it works as expected.

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'classes/membership.php';

$membership = new Membership();



if(isset($_GET["status"]) && $_GET["status"] == "loggedout")

{

    $membership->logOut();

}



if($_POST && !empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["pwd"]))

{

    $response = $membership->validateUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["pwd"]);

}

 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>



<head>



        <title>Login Page</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>



        <body>



            <div>



                <form method="post" action="">

                    <h2>Login <small>enter your credentials</small></h2>



                    <p>

                        <label for="name">Username: </label>

                        <input type="text" name="username" />

                    </p>



                    <p>

                        <label for="pwd">Password: </label>

                        <input type="password" name="pwd" />

                    </p>



                    <p>

                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />

                    </p>



                </form>



                <?php if(isset($response)) echo "<h4>" . $response . "</h4>"; ?>



            </div>



        </body>



</head>
```

site.php

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/membership.php';

$membership = new Membership();

$membership->confirmMember();

echo phpinfo();

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>
  <a href = "index.php?status=loggedout">Log Out</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

membership.php

```
<?php

require_once 'mysql.php';
class Membership
{
  function validateUser($un,$pw)
  {
    $mysql = new Mysql;
    $validateCreds = $mysql->verifyUserAndPass($un,md5($pw));

    if($validateCreds)
    {
      $_SESSION["status"] == "authorized";
      header("location: /site.php");
    }

    else
    {
      return "Enter valid creds.";
    }
  }

  function logOut()
  {
    if(isset($_SESSION["status"]))
    {
      unset($_SESSION["status"]);
    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
    {
      setcookie(session_name(),'',time() - 10000);
    }

    session_destroy();
  }

  function confirmMember()
  {
    if($_SESSION["status"] != "authorized")
    {
      header("location: /index.php");
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

and the Mysql will return true if valid creds are entered.

Expected results are when valid creds are entered the page /site.php should load. Once the user has clicked "log out" on site.php it should not allow them to go to www.example.xyz:8080/site.php and direct them back to index.php

Actual results:
User enters in valid creds and gets re-directed to index.php. In the network web tools in firefox I see the page /site.php was reached but got a HTTP 302 and then index.php loads again so i'm doing something wrong with the sessions.

Comment: You are missing `session_start()` in `site.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing session start. I'd add it to the constructor of the membership class. Might be other things, but I think that's the glaring one.

Also you are using == when setting the session parameter. Use = only.

Comment: it was the == and adding session_start to the membership constructor. Thank you so much!